# Remove all links from categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I have listed all the post categories in my WordPress slider. But there's a problem; the category names are links.

```
if(has_category()) {
    $cats_list = get_the_category_list(', ');
} else {
    $cats_list = 'No categories';
}
```

And it's outputted by this:

```
<?php echo $cats_list; ?>
```

Is there any way to remove the links around it? I've read the WP docs but they don't give me any info about the links.

---

Solved it by creating this:

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    echo $category->cat_name . ' ';
}
```

That still needs some tweaks, though.

Comment: `<?php echo $cats_list; ?>` what it outputs? one example?

Comment: @Anant All the categories of the post, such as Uncategorized, etc.

Comment: you said links are coming,. I am talking about that

Comment: @Anant Yes, a link is wrapped around each category name; `<a href="category/uncategorized/" rel="category tag">Uncategorized</a>`

Comment: https://eval.in/609248

Comment: can you please check my example link?

Comment: @Anant Have checked and tried it out but it seems like it only works for the first category

Comment: you have to apply it for each category in loop or something

Answer (score 0):

A response from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38503771/5970334) could help you:

```
$categories = array()
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    $categories[] = $category->cat_name;
}
echo implode( ', ', $categories );
```

You could also change your echo line to:

```
<?php echo strip_tags($cats_list); ?>
```

Hope it helps!