# A comma issue with foreach

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code. This code is used to display all categories in WordPress.

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    echo $category->cat_name . ', ';
}
```

But even when there's just 1 category showing, the comma behind it is still there. I want it like this:

> - 1 category: [category]
> - 2 categories: [category]**,** [category]
> - And same goes for 3 categories: [category]**,** [category]**,** [category]

Is this possible? I have tried:

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    $getcount = count(get_the_category());
    if($getcount > 1) {
        echo $category->cat_name . ', ';
    } else {
        echo $category->cat_name;
    }
}
```

But that's also not the best solution and when there's more than 1 category, the same issue will accur.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: `$count = 0; foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    echo (!$count ? ',' : '')  . $category->cat_name; $count++;
}`

Comment: Just [implode](http://php.net/implode)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```php
$categories = array();
foreach ((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    $categories[] = $category->cat_name;
}
echo implode(', ', $categories);
```

Answer (score 4):

why don't you use `the_category(', ');`?
It will also list all post categories

Comment: This is probably the most Wordpress-ish way to achieve this. Good call.

Comment: That's a great solution but adds the links to the categories, something I want to avoid.

Comment: @J.Doe Then use [get_the_category_list()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category_list) instead.

Comment: @Oldskool That also adds links for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `implode`:

```
$categories = []
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    $categories[] = $category->cat_name;
}

echo implode(', ', $categories);
```

Or you may use `implode` with `array_map`:

```
echo implode(', ', array_map(function($category) {
    return $category->cat_name;
}, get_the_category()));
```

Answer (score 2):

try using this.

```
   $str = '';
        foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
            $str .= "$category->cat_name , ";
        }
    $str = rtrim($str,', ');
  echo $str;
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is simply to use `implode`after building up an `array` of Category Names within your `foreach` Loop. And it takes just a few lines like so:

```
    <?php
        $catNames = array();
        foreach( (get_the_category()) as $category) {
            $catNames[] = $category->cat_name;
        }
        echo implode(', ', $catNames);
```